# Word meaning before the Biblical Fall?

Tags: single-word-requests

Similar to *antediluvian*, is there a word that literally means before the Fall of Man?

Comment: Perhaps "Adamic"?

Comment: Mesozoic? ... ;)

Comment: The eve of the Fall of Man.

Comment: The Summer of Man.

Comment: The word-or-is-it _pre-fall_ has been used, and is transparent and nicely unsophisticated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Prelapsarian](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prelapsarian) is the usual term. I wouldn't say it is in daily use, but it is at least in non-theological dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The word most like *antediluvian* but meaning not Before the Flood but Before the Fall would necessarily be ***antepeccant***, which has the advantage of being somewhat adapted for English.  However, the word most like *antebellum* would be ***antepeccatum***.  Both mean “before sin”.

Some might prefer to put a hyphen in that to make it ***ante-peccatum***, just as one sometimes sees done with *ante-bellum*, *ante-partum*, and *ante-jentacular*.

But don’t expect to be understood by people who wouldn’t understand those last three, which is probably most people.

Oh sure, those familiar with the Augustine *De Civitate Dei* or Fellini’s *Mens Augustini De Statu Creaturae Rationalis **Ante Peccatum*** will know exactly what you mean.  But quite honestly, how many of those sorts are you likely to encounter?